# BASH Free Space Script: Variation

Tags: bash

I made a script in order to check the available space on root, /var, /tmp, /usr and /opt since I need 1.5G free on each of them. Of course, there are times when all those are in root, not in another partitions.

But I got some error from my script:

1- Sometimes the output its weird when it runs in a non-English System.

2- --output in df -h its not available since some systems are old.

I want to change this script a little bit since I want it to work in every machine and I would like to ask for ideas.

I have tested the script on 650 machines already. 140 of them created the problems that I mention.

```
printf "root=" ; df -h --output=avail / | grep -v Avail | xargs | tr -d '[:space:]'
printf ",opt=" ; df -h --output=avail /opt | grep -v Avail | xargs | tr -d '[:space:]'
printf ",usr=" ; df -h --output=avail /usr | grep -v Avail | xargs | tr -d '[:space:]'
printf ",tmp=" ; df -h --output=avail /tmp | grep -v Avail | xargs | tr -d '[:space:]'
printf ",var=" ; df -h --output=avail /var | grep -v Avail | xargs
```

1- Problem:

- Wrong: root=Dispo 1.5G,var=Dispo 1.5G,usr=Dispo 1.5G,tmp=Dispo
  1.5G,opt=Dispo 1.5G
- Correct: root=1.5G,var=1.5G,usr=1.5G,tmp=1.5G,opt=1.5G

2- Problem:

```
df: Unbekannte Option »--output=avail«
„df --help“ gibt weitere Informationen.
root= opt= usr= tmp= var=
```

EDIT:

Looks like @CharlesDufy answer worked. I made the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo df -h / /var /tmp /opt /usr > freespace.txt

rootSpace=$(awk "NR==2 { print $4 }" freespace.txt)
varSpace=$(awk "NR==3 { print $4 }" freespace.txt)
tmpSpace=$(awk "NR==4 { print $4 }" freespace.txt)
optSpace=$(awk "NR==5 { print $4 }" freespace.txt)
usrSpace=$(awk "NR==6 { print $4 }" freespace.txt)

customProp="root=$rootSpace,var=$varSpace,tmp=$tmpSpace,opt=$optSpace,usr=$usrSpace"

#and the rest....
```

Also I want to ask 2 more questions:

1. Is it possible to take the freespace.txt output without creating a file?
2. If the 4 folders are in root, like they are not separte partitions, my output looks like this

   root=12G,var=12G,tmp=12G,opt=12G,usr=12G

Is there a way to make an output like this without tons of IF, ELIF or ELSE comands?

```
root=12G,var=root,tmp=root,opt=root,usr=root
```

Comment: If you want portable behavior, write your code to depend only on behavior specified in [the POSIX specification for `df`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html#tag_20_33). BTW, you'll have a better time trying to write the whole thing in `awk` (as in, pipe from *one* copy of `df` to *one* copy of `awk`, and do all your logic in the latter); it's a very expressive and powerful language, and the approach in general is much, much faster than running `df` over and over once per partition, piped to a bunch of other external commands that have to be repeatedly started.

Comment: BTW, if you just want to deal with the locale, that's what `LC_ALL=C` is for (as in, `LC_ALL=C df -h /`). So the non-English part is much, *much* easier than the non-GNU (or non-modern) `df` part.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your answer. The non-English causes problem beacuse grep -v could not find the column name, and I have 5 times the df command. not a big problem as you said. Now I am trying to figure out how to do the AWK part which looks really interesting :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It worked perfectly :). I would like to give the correct answer but its a comment and if its possible to ask you another question.

Comment: Sure -- until there's an answer *posted as an answer*, questions are fair game to edit in ways that change their meaning. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I edited the Question. No need to ask if you dont want to. Script already works fine :). Just want to know if I can do it better

Comment: `{ read; read _ _ _ rootSpace _; read _ _ _ _ varSpace; read _ _ _ _ tmpSpace; read _ _ _ _ optSpace; read _ _ _ _ usrSpace; } < <(df -h / /var /tmp /opt /usr)` -- no temporary file, much faster to run (the only external command is `df` itself, everything else is shell builtins).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much for your answer! And sorry for responding late :)